# Imported Eclipse projects not compiling

Tags: java, eclipse, cordova

I installed Eclipse 4.2 in new windows 8, and copied and imported all my projects.  All projects are based on phonegap so have the phonegap build

None will compile and all have red X by the  src> app.java  although they work fine in the original eclipse.

I dont understand the errors so dont know where to start:

My Code:  The error for the line in () not part of code

```
package com.x.x;
import android.os.Bundle;         (ERROR=The import android.os.Bundle cannot be resolved)
import com.phonegap.*;
public class App extends DroidGap {         (ERROR= The hierarchy of the type App is inconsistent)
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override                       (ERROR = Override cannot be resolved to a type)
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {      (ERROR=Bundle cannot be resolved to a type)
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");   (ERROR = The method loadUrl(String) from the type DroidGap refers to the missing type String)
}
}
```

Error line 1:

```
     Multiple markers at this line
- The type android.os.Bundle cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from 
 required .class files
- The type android.content.Intent cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from 
 required .class files
- The type java.lang.String cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from 
 required .class files
- The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from 
 required .class files
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Step one is to resolve your JRE setup, which is obviously not in order (`java.lang.Object` cannot be resolved). Open project properties, Java Build Path, Libraries, and in the list find the item referring to the JRE. Edit this entry. You will probably need to locate the JRE on your filesystem.

Comment: yeah sounds promising - I put jre in a different place in this install.  Ill see if this works -thanks

Comment: Im not sure which library is the JRE one?  I have 3: Phonegap 1.3 jar/Android Dependencies/Unable to get system library for the project.  The last one sounds like it may be an issue!  It has 2 sub options: Access rules:no rules defines/Native library location:(none)

Comment: JRE is not a single file, you must choose the JRE home directory. This is obvious from the GUI dialog that asks you to choose it, isn't it?

Comment: Based on what you said - I added android.jar as an external jar on the properties>Java build path menu, and that got rid of all the errors.  Thanks. I had some other issues I needed to clean up but working - Thanks! Great!

Answer (score 2):

I resolved by following this steps..
 open project properties, java build path, libraries, search for JRE, select that and remove JRE, click on add libraries, select JRE system libraries, click next and check both execution environment and alternative jre than click on finish. Now again open project than select clean. This will clean your project.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the compile setting and check project specific setting and then change the compiler version. This can be resolved from there.

Comment: where is the compile setting?

Comment: Right click on the project from project explorer. Then go to properties. Then select the Java Compiler. From there enable the project specific setting.

Comment: How could you possibly expect to resolve type resolution with a compiler setting? And BTW `@Override` is not a type error in pre-Java 5, but a **syntax error**.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same errors on my project, but I fixed it in a different way, here's what I did:

- Right clicked my android project (the root) and selected Properties
- Clicked on 'Android' on the list towards the left
- Ticked an Android Build from the Build Target list, like Android #.#.# (Android 4.0.3 for example)

Clicked okay and that was it! Cleared all my errors :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Right click on package > Build Path > Configure Build Path
2. Select Java Build Path > click on Classpath, remove the existing JRE libraries.
3. Add Library > JRE system library > Alternate JRE > Installed JRE > Add > Standard VM > Browse the jre folder and point JRE Home to that directory where you installed JRE > Finish.

This should fix the problem.